# How to merge two arrays using overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, merge, operator-overloading

```
class Array
{
public:
    Array(int sze)// default constructor
    {
        size = sze;
        ptr = new int [size];
    }
 //.......
    Array operator += (Array & a1, Array & a2)
    {
    //....
    return 0;
    }
```

For example, if array1 contains
 1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 15
and array2 contains
 3, 4, 7, 13, 19, 21, 25
then after execution of the statement
 array1 += array2
array2 will be unchanged, and array1 will contain
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array& operator += (const Array & a2)
{
//....
return this;
}
```

it should take 1 argument.

a simple approach would be to copy all the contents of `this->ptr` into a temp array and then delete the contents of ptr to fit in old content + new content, allocate bigger memory for `this->ptr` and then copy the contents from the temp array and the contents of a2 , finally return a refference to `this`.

Comment: Take `a2` by const reference, and do the new allocation before freeing the old allocation in case there is an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to merge two arrays:

```
Array & Array::operator +(const Array &sm){
    int i,j;
    this->_size = _size + sm._size;
    for(i = 0; i < _size; i++);
    this->data[i] = data[i];
    for(j = _size; j < sm._size;j++,i++);
    this->data[i] = sm.data[i];
    return *this;
}
```